# What is a practical use of Array.prototype.reduce?

Tags: javascript

From what I understand, this is a commonly used function with a wide range of applicability. The [example on Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

which has the effect of summing the values. Of course, that's not a great example since they couldn't just done `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].sum().`

So what is a real-life situation where, as a web developer, I will be faced with a problem and think, "*Ah, this is a job for `reduce`!*" Either a very obscure situation or a common one where I can use `reduce` as a clever way to solve it.

Comment: It's the same as with many other higher-order constructs .. the 'aha' moment comes only *after* use. Sometimes this can lead to "too much cleverness", but the pendulum usually fixes itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Of course, that's not a great example since they couldn't just done `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].sum()`.

There is no standard `Array#sum` in JavaScript. So that's a use right there: Implementing it:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "sum", {
    value: function() {
        return this.reduce(function(sum, item) { return sum + item; }, 0);
    }
});
```

*(You can actually leave the `, 0` part off in this particular example; if you call `reduce` without a seed value, its first call to the callback uses the first entry as the first argument and the second entry as the secodn.)*

Or any other kind of accumulating operation, such as a product, perhaps using an object property:

```
var foos = [
    {foo: 1},
    {foo: 2},
    {foo: 3}
];
var product = foos.reduce(function(p, obj) {
    return p * obj.foo;
}, 0);
```

Or perhaps an appending operation:

```
var list = [
    {name: "John"},
    {name: "Carla"},
    {name: "Mohammed"}
];
var names = list.reduce(function(acc, obj, index) {
    if (index === list.length - 1) {
        return acc + ", and " + obj.name;
    }
    return acc + ", " + obj.name;
});
```

Just about any operation that involves accumulating values is one where I tend to reach for `reduce`.

Another usage (some would say *abusage*) I commonly see is when you want to do something with each item in the array that involves adding it to a new array or object, such as creating a cross-index of an array by an object property:

```
var list = [
    {id: 1, name: "John"},
    {id: 2, name: "Carla"},
    {id: 3, name: "Mohammed"}
];
var index = list.reduce(function(o, item) {
    o[item.id] = item;
    return o;
}, {});
```

The reason I say "some would say *abusage*" above is that the accumulator (`o`) in the above doesn't actually change; its *state* changes (we add properties to it), but its *value* doesn't, and so in that sense `reduce` isn't being used for it's intended purpose: Building up a value that changes. But I see that kind of use frequently as well, probably because it lets us create `index` in a single expression rather that two.

Comment: Top answer! The first example is a good case for when the initial value can be omitted. ;-) Also, *reduceRight* "abusage" is used frequently (by me at least) to iterate backwards even if the accumulator isn't used.

Comment: @RobG: True. :-) I didn't want to get into the complexity of the different ways to call `reduce`. But actually, it didn't complicate things much.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the .reduce() method for an algorithmic challenge on codewars.com. Here's the challenge:

> Pete likes to bake some cakes. He has some recipes and ingredients.
>   Unfortunately he is not good in maths. Can you help him to find out,
>   how many cakes he could bake considering his recipes?
>
> Write a function cakes(), which takes the recipe (object) and the
>   available ingredients (also an object) and returns the maximum number
>   of cakes Pete can bake (integer). For simplicity there are no units
>   for the amounts (e.g. 1 lb of flour or 200 g of sugar are simply 1 or
>   200). Ingredients that are not present in the objects, can be
>   considered as 0.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> // must return 2
> cakes({flour: 500, sugar: 200, eggs: 1}, {flour: 1200, sugar: 1200, eggs: 5, milk: 200}); 
> // must return 0
> cakes({apples: 3, flour: 300, sugar: 150, milk: 100, oil: 100}, {sugar: 500, flour: 2000, milk: 2000});
> ```

And here is the solution:

```
function cakes(recipe, available) {
  return Object.keys(recipe).reduce(function(val, ingredient) {
    return Math.min(Math.floor(available[ingredient] / recipe[ingredient] || 0), val)
  }, Infinity)  
}
```

Comment: "I just used the .reduce() method for an algorithmic challenge on codewars.com." Haha, very practical real-life situation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have seen another example in ; [https://forum.freecodecamp.com/t/freecodecamp-algorithm-challenge-guide-return-largest-numbers-in-arrays/16042]
They have used this solution;

```
 function largestOfFour(arr) {
     return arr.map(function(group){
return group.reduce(function(prev, current) {
  return (current > prev) ? current : prev;
});
    });
}
```

for this  queston; Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4 sub-arrays.